# Need some clarification for the code provided

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to understand this JavaScript code

```
var arr = [[4, 5, 1, 3], [13, 27, 18, 26], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]];

var main = [];
var long;

for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
    long = arr[i][0]; //setting the long var first element of array
    for(var j=0; j<arr.length; j++){
        //comparing first elelment of array (long) with arr[i][j] ie dynamic
        if(arr[i][j] > long) {
             long= arr[i][j];
        }
    }
     main.push(long);
}
return main;
```

I have understood most of it except the part `long = arr[i][0];`.

I understand that in the `if` statement we are comparing `arr[i][j]` with `arr[i][0]` but the problem is I do not understand how the computer is comparing it.

I have checked `arr[i][0]` and it gives first element of all the arrays present in `arr` array.

I am guessing it is comparing each value with the `arr[i][j]`? but I am not sure.

Can someone please clarify it?

Sorry if this is a silly question I am just a beginner and thank you in advance.

Comment: you calculating the max of each array

Comment: As an aside: you can reduce that code with all the loops down to one ES6 line: `const main = arr.map(a => Math.max.apply(null, a));`

Comment: @andy why not `const main = arr.map(a => Math.max(...arr))` ?

Comment: @JonasW. Your first example works, but your second example doesn't.

Comment: [It usually helps to add a log i side the loop to understand it...](http://jsbin.com/goyemavewe/edit?console)

Comment: @JonasW., I'll remember that `...var` in the future. Thanks for reminding me.

Comment: @Andy I am not yet comfortable with ES6 sticking thats why i used old syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `long = arr[i][0];` is assigning the value is `arr[i][0]` to `var long`. That is setting the first value of each array to the longest value. Then it will iterate through the rest of the values of the array and if it finds a value larger than `long`, it will assign that value to `long` with this block of code

```
if(arr[i][j] > long) {
     long= arr[i][j];
}
```

Then, finish processing the rest of the array.

Finally largest value of that array, `long` will get pushed to `main`.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I am still not able to grasp this one. long = arr[i][j] = 4, 13, 32, 1000. How var long can take this many numbers while it's not an array?

Comment: Var long only contains one number at a time. Each time a larger value is found, the previous value gets overwritten by the new value.

Answer (score 0):

This code snippet is searching this 2D array for the largest values of each nested array. On the initial assignment operation `long = arr[i][0]` the author is assigning the first element of each nested array to `long` on each iteration of the outer loop. On each iteration of the nested(inner) loop we are stepping through a nested array, comparing each element with what `long` points to(first item of this nested array) if that value is larger than long(predicate is satisfied) than push it to `main`, else continue to step through this array searching for the largest value; if `long` is the largest, than push it to `main`. This is a algorithm to find the largest value in a 2D dimensional array.

on each iteration of the outer loop, `long` is being rebound(referencing a new value, that is of a nested array).

The output would be:

```
main = [5, 27, 39, 1001];
```